# Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed, index already specified

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with AngularJS repeaters:

```
<table class="data_table" style="margin: 0 5px; width: calc(100% - 10px);">
  <tr>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th ng-repeat="date in activitiesRangeInfo.labels">{{date | date: 'd/MM'}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="activity in activitiesRangeInfo.generated_datasets track by $index">
    <th>{{activitiesRangeInfo.all_activities[$index]}}</th>
    <td align="center" ng-repeat="inner in activitiesRangeInfo.generated_datasets[$index] track by $index">
      {{inner | number: 1}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this data set:

```
$scope.activitiesRangeInfo = {
  all_activities: ["Tennis"],
  generated_datasets: [[0, 0, 420, 0]],
  labels: JSON.parse('["2016-10-22T13:00:00.000Z","2016-10-23T13:00:00.000Z","2016-10-24T13:00:00.000Z","2016-10-25T13:00:00.000Z"]')
}
```

and this error:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: inner in activity track by $indexb, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: 0
```

Please have a look and advise as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$indexb` isn't valid because it is an Angular defined property. Just use `$index`. If you want to define your own see this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit